# LibGDX Does Not Render Properly

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering

The following is the way LibGDX (on Android) renders a 3d hand model (the 3d model was in fbx format and I converted it to g3db format using fbx-conv application).

[image]

As you see, there are dark patches on the hand. However, when the same model is rendered in Unity3d, Blender or Unreal Engine, it looks properly.

In order to solve the issue, I made sure the normals are outward (I checked that with Blender and also ran a command in Blender to make all normals outward). It did not help. Also I added additional directional lights and increased ambient light in libGDX. Again, it did not help.

```
modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
    modelLeftHand = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("data/Hand_R_.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
...
        // create environment for lighting
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.8f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f, 0f, 0f));
...// In The render() function...
    modelBatch.render(modelLeftHand,environment);
```

Comment: Sure it's not getting clipped by the camera frustum?

Comment: @Tenfour04: No. I zoomed out and tried to look at it from different angles and distances. It didn't help.